# Django ManyToManyField object automatically saves itself

Tags: python, django, django-models, manytomanyfield

I am trying to create an Ecommerce website using Django. I have orderProducts as a ManyToMany field to the Cart object. The question is why whenever I create an OrderProduct object, any existing Cart automatically saves the orderProduct in itself. Here is my model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField('post date:', default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def add_to_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("add_to_cart", kwargs={
            'product_id' : self.pk
        })


class OrderProduct(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name

    def delete_from_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("delete_from_cart", kwargs={
            'product_name' : self.product.name
        })


class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(OrderProduct)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

This is the add_to_cart function, even when I commented out the cart.products.add code, OrderProduct is still added to the carts.

```
def add_to_cart(request,product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product,pk=product_id)
    order_product,created = OrderProduct.objects.get_or_create(product=product,user=request.user)
    cart_qs = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    if cart_qs.exists():
        cart = cart_qs[0]
        if cart.products.filter(product__name=product.name).exists():
            order_product.quantity += 1
            order_product.save()
        else:
            return redirect("cart")
            #cart.products.add(order_product)
        return redirect("cart")
    else:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(user=request.user)
        #cart.products.add(order_product)
        return redirect("products")
```

This is the cart view

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def cart(request):
    # order_product_list = OrderProduct.objects.order_by('-product__price')
    cart,created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    order_product_list = cart.products.all()
    order_product_list = OrderProduct.objects.order_by('-product__price')
    total = 0
    for order_product in order_product_list:
        total += order_product.product.price * order_product.quantity

    context = {
        'products' : order_product_list,
        'total' : total,
    }

    return render(request,'login/cart.html',context)
```

Comment: You sure you are not falling under the case where `if cart.products.filter(product__name=product.name).exists():` this is true because of preexisting data? By the way notice that in that branch you have a concurrency problem, take a look at [this part of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) on how to to do the +1 update correctly

Comment: I tried a few times with the OrderProduct being empty in the database

Comment: Then please show your Cart view. Maybe the bug is there

Comment: Hi, I just added my cart view as well, would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so your bug is here

```py
order_product_list = OrderProduct.objects.order_by('-product__price')
```

There you override your products' list with all the `OrderProduct` regardless they belong to the current cart or not.

Instead of that you should be doing

```py
order_product_list = cart.products.order_by('-product__price')
```

Comment: As soon as I took a look at the cart, that line got my attention. I was just about to say that I might have figured out the problem there, thanks a lot for helping.